# Taxonomy Reference Based on Taxonomy Field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a taxonomy with a custom field: field_uid

Users are able to create their own taxonomy terms, and when they do, field_uid is set to their UID.

I also have a content type which allows users to select terms from a common vocabulary, however, I only want them to have access to terms that they themselves created (IE terms with field_uid = current user's uid).

I've tried using entityreference and views to do this, but views seems unable to cope with taxonomy fields very well.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to my mind:

1. For the view make sure to do a taxonomy or user view and add a relationship to each other.
2. You can also use the private taxonomy module: http://drupal.org/project/private_taxonomy

Comment: I managed to do it. I was stupid and didn't set the view type to taxonomy. That gave me access to the field I needed. Then under the advanced menu I could use a contextual filter to match the field_uid with the currently logged in user's uid.

Comment: Perfect, glad that it work out for you.